# Yum crashed and Gnome desktop is disappear and unable to use yum now

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I am using centOS7 and i was doing the yum update and my electricity went out and PC crashed. When I restart it only terminal appeared with command line. I tried to yum update again but am getting the error

```
There was a problem importing one of the python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was : 

/lib64/librpm.so.3: file too short

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.
```

to check if the internet is working in my machine, I ran the command `ifconfig` and it returns only localhost address and no internet connection is there. Then I ran the command `nmcli d` and it returned

```
nmcli: error while loading shared libraries: /lib64/libss13.so: file too short
```

So basically what i did understand is my all library is crashed and i don't have internet connection. How do I fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I think after the update you have damage on `.so`
you can find the package it belongs to:

`yum provides \*/librpm.so.3`

In my case, I don't have librpm but i have libgcc_s.so.1

**so**:

```
$ yum provides \*/libgcc_s.so.1 
[...]
libgcc-8.3.1-5.el8.0.2.x86_64 : GCC version 8 shared support library
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Filename    : /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
[...]
```

in this case i want `libgcc-8.3.1-5.el8.0.2.x86_64`, you will get another version.

You need to reinstall that package.

`yum reinstall libgcc-8.3.1-5.el8.0.2.x86_64`

in your case you can find libss13 and reinstall the package.

Comment: My yum isn't working at all. commanding yum will result in package error. i have mentioned in my question.

Comment: is rpm command work? @RahulGupta

Comment: if i am just hitting rpm. it doesn't give any error though. ifconfig is resulting in LOOPBACK status

Comment: rpm -qf /lib64/librpm.so.3 
PLZ send the result

Comment: It is executing without error but giving nothing in return. just blank

Comment: ok there is no librpm package or missed you can search [here](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/package-browser) and download the librpm package, after that  use this `rpm2cpio [PACKAGE].rpm | cpio -idmv`

Comment: I hope this is works for you.

Comment: I have iso file of centos 7 so i got all the rpm file which i mount with USB Drive and after executing the command `rpm2cpio *.rpm | cpio -idmv` but i got this message: cpio: premature end of archive

Comment: You don't need all rpm packages, just unpack what you need and copy to the path.

Comment: Try this:  `rpm -Uvh <package.rpm>` 
perhaps it works for you.